# Run into and go out or go into and run out

Tags: verbs

I have a piece of homework that is filling appropriate words into the blanks

> The robber ...... into a bank and took the money. He put it in a bag and then he .... out.

**ran** and **went** are given, but I don’t know if they should be **ran into** and **went out** or **went into** and **ran out**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically speaking, either choice is correct.

In natural speech (outside the context of this exercise), I would probably say **went into / ran out**. *Went* does carry the same level of action or urgency as *ran* in this context. In other words, I imagine the robber calmly walking into the bank. This is not expressed with *ran*. I imagine him hurriedly escaping the bank--*running*.

However, someone else could see it the other way. It depends on how you picture it or what you want to convey. I could be wrong, but I can't really see a good justification to choose one over the other in an exercise/exam. I would be inclined to challenge an "incorrect" mark here.